# How do you add a new player life in C# when you get a certain score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This seems very simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is the code:

```
    if(score >= 3000)
    {
        FindObjectOfType<GameSession>().AddLife();
    }
```

The problem is that once I've reached and surpassed 3000, the condition is such that my score is always above 3000 and so a new life keeps getting added ad infinitum. If I just use '=' operand, however, my score could just jump above 3000 without equaling it and the life will not be added. How do I just add a single life when the score equals or is greater than 3000?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify if you are trying to add once or add each increment of 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some sort of control for that.
For example :

```
bool isAdded = false; // add this outside of the method that contains if statement


if(score >= 3000)
{
    if(!isAdded){
    FindObjectOfType<GameSession>().AddLife();
    isAdded = true;
    }
    
}
```

And reset it anywhere you like. For example when the game resets. `isAdded = false`

Comment: Thanks, this works well, not sure why I didn't see it. Still new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class field that is not just a static number, `3000`, but that you can increase as the player passes each score to beat.

```
static int _lives = 1;
static int _increment = 3000;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int scoreToBeat = 0;
            
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        var score = i;

        if (score >= scoreToBeat)
        {
            AddLife();
            scoreToBeat += _increment;
        }
    }

}

static void AddLife()
{
    _lives += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nate, but I prefer the other answer because it's a bit simpler and I'm a rookie coder!